# Aligning three small box together with a text

Tags: macros, horizontal-alignment, boxes

I made through creating the boxes inside a box with help of an expert by this link [Is three boxes inside a box posibble in latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84075/is-three-boxes-inside-a-box-possible-in-latex)

Now im being troubled on how will i put into command to align this three boxes together with a text horizontally without a box?

Sample output would be like:

[image: sample output will be]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Below I have defined `\UnboxedQuestion`, which changes the style to be inline, and the first optional parameter defines the style to be used for the boxes:

[image]

The default text width is set to `6.0cm` (as shown above). However, this can be adjusted via the second optional parameter:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcommand*{\HorizontalSpacing}{\hfill}% equally spaced boxes
%\newcommand*{\HorizontalSpacing}{\hspace*{2.0cm}}% fixed space boxes

\newlength{\InnerSep}
\setlength{\InnerSep}{0.1cm}

\newcommand{\Boxed}[2][]{%
    % #1 = box draw/fill options
    % #2 = text
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline, inner sep=2pt, outer sep=0]
            \node [#1] (Origin) {#2};
            \draw [thick, draw=black, #1] 
                (Origin.south west) rectangle (Origin.north east) ;
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}


\tikzset{Inner Box Style/.style={
    inner sep=2pt, yshift=0.7ex, 
    text width=1ex, minimum height=2ex
    }
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\UnboxedQuestion}{O{} O{6.0cm} m m m m}{%
    % #1 = optional draw options for inner boxes
    % #2 = text of question
    % #3 = choice 1
    % #4 = choice 2
    % #5 = choice 3
    \noindent\parbox[c]{#2}{%
        \begin{enumerate}[series=UnboxedLists, resume=UnboxedLists]%
            \item #3\strut%
        \end{enumerate}%
    }%
    \hfill\hspace*{\InnerSep}\Boxed[Inner Box Style, #1]{}\,#4%
    \HorizontalSpacing\Boxed[Inner Box Style, #1]{}\,#5%
    \HorizontalSpacing\Boxed[Inner Box Style, #1]{}\,#6%
    \hspace*{\InnerSep}\null%
}%

\newcommand{\ShortTitle}{Is this what you are looking for?}
\newcommand{\LongTitle}{Is this what you are looking for? 
    But what happens if the text is much longer?
    Well in that case I guess it should wrap.}

\begin{document}
\UnboxedQuestion
    {Is this what you are looking for?}
    {YES}{NO}{NONE}

\medskip
\UnboxedQuestion[draw=blue, fill=yellow!50]
    {\LongTitle}
    {YES}{NO}{NONE}


\medskip
\UnboxedQuestion
    [solid, draw=blue, fill=orange!50][5.0cm]
    {\LongTitle}
    {YES}{NO}{NONE}

\medskip
\UnboxedQuestion
    [solid, ultra thick, draw=blue, fill=orange!50][7.5cm]
    {\LongTitle}
    {YES}{NO}{NONE}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sir, This is exactly the form i want but why is it when I add some more text to `Is this what you are looking for` the 3 boxes went down the line. I somehow want the three small boxes in static. Like the number 2 in the sample output i indicated above :)

Comment: Sir I changed `\UnboxedQuestion {Is this what you are looking for?}` to `\UnboxedQuestion {Is this what you are looking for? e text here text here text here text here text here}` See what happens to the three small boxes.. :)

Comment: I updated the solution a few minutes ago, please try the new version and let me know if that solves you problem. If not, please compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that illustrates the problem.

Comment: Oh,and no need to use "Sir".. Makes me feel old, not that I am not... :-)

Comment: I think this will be the solution to my prob. I'll just adjust the spaces. Thanks!

Comment: Oh sorry. Its just my way of showing respect to an expert. :) Anyway TY again.

Comment: i have concerned with the text that i will write. I would like to make the text/questions into order so i'd like to use the `question` command for its numbering. But when i try to use it, the text got boxes and appears as if its no longer presentable. What should I do with it?

Comment: @kayla: Please show what you have tried by composing a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem. And post that as part of the question. Your specifications are not clear. Do you always want every `\UnboxedQuestion` automatically numbered, or do you only sometimes want them numbered?

Comment: i just added `\begin{questions}` after `\begin{document}` then inserted `\question` command like: `\UnboxedQuestion
    \question {Is this what you are looking for?}
    {YES}{NO}{NONE}`.. i would prefer every question be automatically numbered to be precise and organized as well.

Comment: @kayla: You said "when i try to use it, the text got boxes and appears as if its no longer presentable" I don't see how the code snippet reproduces this problem? Also, I don't see your attempt at numbering. Please refer to the link of what a [MWE, minimum working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228)  is.

Comment: @kayla: Updated answer to provide numbering.

Comment: i used the updated solution in my document. But it is noy-working. It says " Package keyval error: series undefined" and it usually points out to `{YES}{NO}{NONE}`

Comment: @kayla: I can reproduce your problem with TeXLive2010, but works fine with TeXLive 2011, and 2012. You could try to update your packages, but I would recommend you upgrade to the 2012 release.