# Is there other possible way for continuous numbering?

Tags: numbering, environments

I am creating a document using exam class. I have four question types here which i had created each a command. Is there facility to enforce continuous numbering for each question types instead of using the `\begin{questions}` ended with `\end{questions}`.

### example:

```
I. True or False Question type
 1. ____ text text text text text text.
 2. ____ text text text text text text.
 3. ____ text text text text text text.

II. Enumeration
 4. Elements of  nature
 5. text text text text text text.
 6. text text text text text text.
```

The sequence of the number in Part I is continued in the Part II. How can I make something like this one?

Answer (score 6):

Try the `enumitem` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item First question
  \item Second question
\end{enumerate}

Some other stuff...

\begin{enumerate}[resume]
  \item More items 
  \item ...
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

For more complicated nesting, you might want to use the `series` option of the package.

Comment: the `enumitem` package no longer works when i used the `\item` command inside the question type `truefalse` -- new command. `\truefalse` found in this link http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84646/create-a-two-column-static-small-box

Comment: I guess in that case, you will have to make a counter of your own. See here for details: http://www.personal.ceu.hu/tex/counters.htm (Simply create a new counter and define a command that will return sequential numbers.)

Answer (score 1):

Simply put `\setcounter{tfno}{0}` before defining the `truefalse` environment as in this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,graphicx}
\usepackage{array,enumitem}
\usepackage{longtable}
\newcounter{tfno}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{2}
\newcommand{\mybox}{\resizebox{.5cm}{!}{\raisebox{-.5ex}{$\Box$}}}
%
\setcounter{tfno}{0} %% moved here
\newenvironment{truefalse}{%
%\setcounter{tfno}{0}  %% moved up
\setlength\LTleft{0pt}
\setlength\LTright{0pt}
\begin{longtable}{>{\stepcounter{tfno}\thetfno.}cp{.5\textwidth}@{\extracolsep{\fill}}cc}
\multicolumn{1}{r}{}&  & \fbox{\parbox{.75cm}{True}} & \fbox{\parbox{.75cm}{False}}  \\
}{%
\end{longtable}
}
\newcommand\tfquestion[1]{ & #1 & \mybox  & \mybox  \\}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\Roman*.]
\item First set of questions
\begin{truefalse}
  \tfquestion{This is a sample text.}
  \tfquestion{This is another sample short text.}
  \tfquestion{This is a long line containing text and wrapping into second line without hitting the boxes}
\end{truefalse}
%
\item Second set comes here.
\begin{truefalse}
  \tfquestion{This is a sample text.}
  \tfquestion{This is another sample short text.}
  \tfquestion{This is a long line containing text and wrapping into second line without hitting the boxes}
\end{truefalse}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is this also possible in using the `exam document class` especially using the `\begin{questions}` and `\end{questions}`? i tried it but when I compiled the file, the number instead proceeding to 7 it started again with 1. What  should I do about this?

Comment: @Kayla Please provide the full code that is giving trouble.

Comment: Sir, `exam.cls` is an open source i think. Can be downloaded here http://ctan.cdpa.nsysu.edu.tw/macros/latex/contrib/exam/exam.cls There you'll find the questions environment `\newenvironment{questions}`. I don't understand it since it is connected all over other command in the class.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to have the question numbers start over again from 1, then don't end the `questions` environment.  You can use the standard LaTeX `\section` command to insert your section headings, and if you enclose the `\section` command in the argument of a `\fullwidth` command, it won't be indented.  For example, if you type

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}
\begin{questions}
\fullwidth{\section{True or false question types}}
  \question This is one of the questions.
  \question This is one of the questions.
  \question This is one of the questions.

\fullwidth{\section{Enumeration}}
  \question This is one of the questions.
  \question This is one of the questions.
  \question This is one of the questions.
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

then you'll get

[image]

Comment: not all of the new commands i declared in my own class depends on the `questions` environment. Some of the new commands can generate sequence of numbers not by using the questions environment. If i will use the questions environment which allows automatic numbering and the commands with automatic numbering together, then conflict or errors may be produced. It is advisable for some but in my case, it is not advisable.

Comment: Sir i have used the command in the second solution from this thread and your solution using `exam` 
Assuming those variables are declared. the output of this code does not follow what supposed to be the order of number in each section/part.
    `\begin{document}
    \section{First set of questions}
    \begin{truefalse}
    \tfquestion{text}
    \tfquestion{text text text}
    \tfquestion{text text text}
    \end{truefalse}
    \section{Second set comes here.}
    \begin{questions}
    \question{text text}
    \question{text text}
    \question{text }
    \end{questions}
    \end{document}`

Comment: @Kayla: The exam class assumes that all of your questions will be produced by the `\question` command; if you try to combine the questions environment with some other commands to produce questions, you're looking for trouble.  That being said: If you give the command `\setcounter{question}{\value{tfno}}` immediately following `\begin{questions}`, then the sequence of question numbers will be as you want.  However: Many parts of the exam class (e.g., `\ifcontinuation`, `\ContinuedQuestion`, etc.) will not work.

Comment: is it possible to create an optional command like the `\pointsinmargin` used by the `exam` class? and takes by the question types as an optional argument?

Comment: Sir, is it possible to create an optional command like the \pointsinmargin used by the exam class? and takes by the question types as an optional argument? for example: `\enforcednumbering` which when used numbers of different  question types used where continuous. `part 1: 1,2,3,4 partII: 5,6,7

Comment: @Kayla: You seem to be asking about extensions to the code in other people's answers to your question.  I'm the author of the exam class, which is why I've been answering questions related to that, but you should ask those other people about their code.  Again, I should point out that if you try to use the questions environment for only some of your questions and other code to generate other questions, many things in the exam class will not work; you're much safer trying to get your questions formatted as you want after giving a `\question` command.

Comment: Sir, I know you are the  author. Glad am I that you comment on the thread. I am using your exam doc as a guide in creating the questionnaire. Still i'm a novice and mine still need lots of explanations but i'll analyze on my own and probably create some argument which will somehow solve the problem. Thank you. :)