# Remove the automatic generation of number?

Tags: numbering, environments, questionnaire

I looked for my past thread which can be found here: [Create a two column static small box](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84646/create-a-two-column-static-small-box) the solution i accepted was the `truefalse` environment. My question is, how will i remove the automatic numbering of the environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The numbering is inserted by

```
 >{\stepcounter{rowno}\therowno.}
```

or

```
>{\stepcounter{tfno}\thetfno.}
```

so just delete that part.  `>{}` is `array` package notation to insert code at the start of every cell in the column, `\stepcounter` increases the counter `\thexxx` prints the counter and `.` prints a dot.