# Why do i have error by removing this `>{\stepcounter{tfno}\thetfno.}`

Tags: errors, exam, questionnaire

i followed the instructions by this link:
[Remove the automatic generation of number?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100042/remove-the-automatic-generation-of-number/100043#100043)
and happily satisfied when it really prevented the automatic numbering of the text. But why is when i changed the document class to `\documentclass{exam}` it suddenly provides me eror. 
i have this code here:

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{amssymb,graphicx}
\usepackage{array} 
\usepackage{longtable}
\newcounter{tfno}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{2}
\newcommand{\mybox}{\resizebox{.5cm}{!}{\raisebox{-.5ex}{$\Box$}}}

\newenvironment{truefalse}{%
\setcounter{tfno}{0}
\setlength\LTleft{0pt}
\setlength\LTright{0pt}
 \begin{longtable}{cp{.5\textwidth}@{\extracolsep{\fill}}cc}
\multicolumn{1}{r}{}&  & \fbox{\parbox{.75cm}{True}} & \fbox{\parbox{.75cm}     
{False}}  \\
}{%
\end{longtable}
}
\newcommand\tfquestion[1]{ & #1 & \mybox  & \mybox  \\}
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\begin{truefalse}
\question\tfquestion{This is a sample text.}
 \question\tfquestion{This is another sample short text.}
  \question\tfquestion{This is a long line containing text and wrapping into  
second line without hitting the boxes}
\end{truefalse} 
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

How can I fix the error?

Answer (score 4):

The `questions` environment of the `exam` class is a list environment, and you try to put a `longtable` within it, no wonder you bump into problems.

I followed the links to your two other questions, and you should have from the start mentioned that your intent was to use the `exam` class. This would have avoided to people to spend time on providing solutions which end up being incompatible with this requirement.

I recommend you read the manual of the `exam` class, as it provides some possibilities for customize the format of question (I am not familiar with it but I saw there is macro called `\qformat`). In the meantime the following provides something like what you seem to be trying to achieve:

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{amssymb,graphicx}

\newcommand{\mybox}{\resizebox{.5cm}{!}{\raisebox{-.5ex}{$\Box$}}}
\newcommand\tfquestion[1]{%
  \parbox[t]{.5\textwidth}{#1}\hfill\mybox\quad\mybox}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
  \question\tfquestion{This is a sample text.}
  \question\tfquestion{This is another sample short text.}
  \question\tfquestion{This is a long line containing text and wrapping into  
second line without hitting the boxes}
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

[image: questions]

As per OP's request, I can propose the following. This is a bit complicated because I wanted to make absolutely sure that no page break would ever happen after the `True-False` boxes and before the actual questions.

But: I am not even sure the `questions` environment of the `exam` class is supposed to be used many times; indeed doing that generates `multiply-defined labels` errors, and I tried it in a vanilla example just using the `exam` class and nothing from the code here, just repeated `questions` environments. The work put into making the page-breaks impossible at the wrong places may just have been a bit in waste if one is supposed to use only once this environment (the manual is long and I did not have time to read it).

The environment is called `truefalsequestions` and each item is to be input as `\tfquestion{the text of the question within braces like this}`. There is an optional parameter which defaults to `.9` and says how much of the available space is to be used as width of the multi-lines questions.

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{amssymb,graphicx}

% \newcommand\tfquestion[1]{%
%   \parbox[t]{.5\textwidth}{#1}\hfill\mybox\quad\mybox}

\newsavebox{\TrueBox}
\sbox{\TrueBox}{\fboxrule1pt\fbox{True}}

\newsavebox{\FalseBox}
\sbox{\FalseBox}{\fboxrule1pt\fbox{False}}

\newcommand{\mybox}{\resizebox{.5cm}{!}{\raisebox{-.5ex}{$\Box$}}}

\newsavebox{\TwoBoxes}
\sbox{\TwoBoxes}{\makebox[\wd\TrueBox] {\mybox}\quad
                 \makebox[\wd\FalseBox]{\mybox}}

\newcommand\tfquestion[1]{} % will be overwritten

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{truefalsequestions}[1][.9] % defaults to 90% of available space
  {\renewcommand\tfquestion[1]{%
      \question
      \parbox[t]{#1\dimexpr\textwidth-\leftmargin-\wd\TwoBoxes\relax}{##1}%
        \hfill\usebox{\TwoBoxes}}%
   \par\bigskip
   \hb@xt@\linewidth{\hss\usebox{\TrueBox}\quad\usebox{\FalseBox}}%
   \nointerlineskip
   \kern\medskipamount\nopagebreak
   \@nobreaktrue
   \begin{questions}}
  {\end{questions}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{truefalsequestions}
  \tfquestion{This is a sample text.}

  \tfquestion{This is another sample short text.}

  \tfquestion{This is a long line containing text and wrapping into  
second line without hitting the boxes. This is a long line containing text and
wrapping into second line without hitting the boxes.}

  \tfquestion{This is a sample text.}
\end{truefalsequestions}


\begin{truefalsequestions}[.6]
  \tfquestion{This is a sample text.}

  \tfquestion{This is another sample short text.}

  \tfquestion{This is a long line containing text and wrapping into  
second line without hitting the boxes. This is a long line containing text and
wrapping into second line without hitting the boxes.}

  \tfquestion{This is a sample text.}
\end{truefalsequestions}

\end{document}
```

[image: refined questions environment]

Comment: How will i include the "TRUE" "FALSE" as column labels  found in this link http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84646/create-a-two-column-static-small-box??