# Create two small box after text?

Tags: macros, boxes, two-column

how should i declare a command for two small boxes after text in every line? based from this link [Create a two column static small box](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84646/create-a-two-column-static-small-box). I need to remove the automatic printing of its numbers. What should I do?

example output is:
[image]

i put include this code in my class but it gives me errors

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,graphicx} 
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}
\newcounter{tfno}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{2}
\newcommand{\mybox}{\resizebox{.5cm}{!}{\raisebox{-.5ex}{$\Box$}}}
\newcommand\tfquestion[1]{ & #1 & \mybox  & \mybox  \\}
\begin{document}
\tfquestion{This is a sample text.}
\tfquestion{This is another sample short text.}
 \tfquestion{This is a long line containing text and wrapping into second line 
 without hitting the boxes}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: How is this different that you earlier question: [Aligning three small box together with a text](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84141/aligning-three-small-box-together-with-a-text) except that the previous question had 3 boxes and this has 2?

Comment: the previous should have labels {yes} {no} while these one was pure small boxes only.

Comment: I removed other commands from that link to have the two boxes but it provides me error. I removed the declaration of `\newenvironment{trueflase}` and keep only this command:
`\newcommand{\mybox}{\resizebox{.5cm}{!}{\raisebox{-.5ex}{$\Box$}}}` and `\newcommand\tfquestion[1]{ & #1 & \mybox  & \mybox  \\}` what should i do now.

Comment: @Kayla: Please address users directly using comments if you have questions about the links they post. Moderator flags are for administrative purposes only. Thanks.